# yum + how to enable repo in yum when enabled=0

Tags: linux, rpm, yum, rhel

we have the following repo on our rhel 7.2 server

as we can see we set the `enabled=0` , as default

```
more infra-update.repo
[infra-76-update]
name=infra 76 update
baseurl=http://linux_machine/infra-76
gpgcheck=0
enabled=0
```

but in case we want to use this repo - `infra-7.6` , we wripte the following yum syntax

```
yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=infra-76 update -y
```

but we get

```
Error getting repository data for infra-76, repository not found
```

but when we set the `enabled=1` , then we can do the installation of yum successfully with - ( `yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=infra-76 update -y` )

but the question is:

is it possible to enable repo as `yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=infra-76` , while `enabled=0` ??

NOTE - the target is to install the rpm's from repo `infra-76` in spite the parameter in repo config is `enabled=0`

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to get an idea why this is off-topic here. Also, make sure you read the description of tags that you apply before applying them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `yum-config-manager` (you might need to install `yum-utils`) :

```
yum-config-manager --enable infra-76
```

The flags `--disablerepo` and `--enablerepo` disable/enable the repositories temporarily (just for that command, in this case just for running `yum update` this one time).

Comment: do you mean to do ? yum --disablerepo=*  yum-config-manager --enable infra-76 update -y

Comment: no. One shot, make sure repository is available for yum to use: `yum-config-manager --enable infra-76`. This is persistent. Then `yum update -y`. repository remains enabled forever. If for a single command you want to disable it, you could: `yum --disable-repo=infra-76 install some-package`.